# Run windows containers on M1 Mac

Tags: .net, docker, apple-m1, windows-container, utm

I've been tasked with building and deploying a dotnet application in a windows container.

This has been done previously on Intel macs using this project:

https://github.com/StefanScherer/windows-docker-machine

I am using however an M1 mac, and the above of course won't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions to use windows images locally, without having to use amd64 hardware?

In particular I'd need to run on M1:

[mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk/?tab=description)

[mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-wcf/)

I tried to follow the guidance at https://github.com/StefanScherer/windows-docker-machine/issues/84

but honestly it's a bit over my head.

I ran the project successfullly on an Intel mac, verified that the same steps (build and run the image) won't work on M1.

Attempted to run a windows machine running Docker via [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/) with no success (windows 10 runs but cannot have Docker running within it).

Answer (score 1):

So, if you can run a VM on a MAC, you should be able to get Windows containers to work. The problem you're facing there is that - I'm assuming you're using - Docker Desktop also tries to enable Hyper-V, which won't work in your case. Try to run this instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce#windows-server-1 This should work on Windows Server VM, but I believe it also works on Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you pointed me in the right direction. I got so focused on Docker Desktop that I forgot the simplest option, to simply install the Docker engine for windows. Simple tests with UTM + docker engine (first option in the link you provided) are encouraging, I could run a simple windows container on a windows 10 installation in UTM. Will keep playing around, even though for my business needs I ended up just spinning an EC2 instance with Windows Server, it was just the quickest and safest option.

Comment: @LinuxPronto - Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Hi @MikeJansen
No unfortunately I didn't make any progress, I stopped trying.
What's your situation?